# how to find out what is causing I/O in my application?

Tags: c#, windows, profiling, process-explorer

Good afternoon,

I inherited some C# code from years ago. I have refactored it a bit to be asynchronous.
Evaluating the impact of my changes on the performance of the CPU, I used [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to watch, roughly, what my app was doing.
To my surprise, it appears to be doing what Process Explorer reports as I/O. In general, this is related to Disk I/O or Network I/O.
Based on what I can see of the code, I can't figure out an explicit call to either of those 2 I/O sources.

My question is: ***what is the best way to identify which section of code is causing I/O?*** We use [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) from JetBrains to profile our application, but, from what I can tell, it only handles CPU and Memory performance.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Regards,

Eric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Process Monitor may be your answer.  Refer to the following StackOverflow question for more information.

[How can I profile file I/O?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493177/how-can-i-profile-file-i-o/493201#493201)

Building on that answer, you may be able to search your solution for the filename of any commonly read or written files found with Process Monitor.

Comment: +1.  I find the Process Activity Summary function invaluable for seeing at a glance which files are being accessed the most.

Comment: Thanks a lot. While it didn't show which part of my code was doing it, as soon as I saw which file was being accessed, I nailed it. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

The [stackshot method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743504/any-references-on-dynamic-code-analysis/3745797#3745797), also called random pausing, will find it, if it takes significant time.

Answer (score 1):

If the I/O code is managed, you can load the symbols for the .net framework and set breakpoints in crucial functions (e.g. `FileStream` constructors etc.)

It involves some guess work but can be informative if you succeed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Process Monitor, I find the Resource Monitor on Win7 (also available under 'Performance and Reliability' I think on Vista) very useful for diagnosing I/O-related slowdowns. Switch to the disk view and sort by Read/Write or Total (win7 only).  Also keep an eye on the list of files that appear.